# How to subquery in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

The result is tony and alex, their book appears in two different types. tom appears in three types, so it is not a result. How can I write query statement to realize it? THANKS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the output shown in your question group by Author only and use a having clause to filter on an aggregation.

```
SELECT
      A.author
    , COUNT(DISTINCT I."Type")
FROM authorCollection A
      INNER JOIN book I ON A.key = I.key
                  AND I."TYPE" <> 'UNKNOWN'
GROUP BY
      A.author
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT I."Type") = 2
```

To count the number of authors that meet that criteria (asked subsequently) make the query above a "derived table", like this:

```
SELECT
      COUNT(*) as num_of_authors
FROM (
      SELECT
            A.author
      FROM authorCollection A
            INNER JOIN book I ON A.key = I.key
                        AND I."TYPE" <> 'UNKNOWN'
      GROUP BY
            A.author
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT I."Type") = 2
      ) AS derived
```

Note I removed the second column in that derived table as it isn't needed for the result, but also note that the having clause of the derived table query will still work as it did before.

Comment: it works! But if I just want to get the total number of authors that satisfy the requirement mentioned above, others keep the same. (don't need to get the author's name)How can I achieve this? Thanks!!!

Comment: wrap that query inside another. (so it becomes a "derived table") will amend answer